# creating two frontpages in moodle

Tags: moodle

is there anyway to create two homepages for moodle or someway of doing something similar to having a two homepage effect.

At my work (educational) we offer qualifications and we also offer online (e-learning) courses.

Ideally I want to create one area just for the qualifications where users will get a login and ONLY see the qualifications side of things.

Then I want to make another area JUST for the e-learning side of things. Both sets of users would not be able to see the other areas (ie. e-learning cannot see qualifications etc)

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Hopefully this makes sense.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to have a single front page and then restrict access to individual courses based on their [enrollment status](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Enrolments).

You can add an [additional plugin](https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_apply) to allow for self-enrollment with administrative approval.

Additionally, you can do things like [hide specific courses](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Course_settings#Visible) or categories of courses and then configure permissions to view these hidden courses or [hidden categories](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Capabilities/moodle/category:viewhiddencategories).

If you want to create completely unique landing pages, you may need to manage more than one instance of Moodle.